# How to check if first command line argument is a directory within your current directory in JAVA?

Tags: java

I'm currently able to list out the contents of my current directory by using the code below.  However, I want to add a command line argument to list out the contents of a directory within the current directory.  I'm having trouble checking if args[0] is a directory within my current directory.  Here is my current code.  The top part works, until I reached the commented NOT WORKING section.  How do I check if arg[0] is a directory within the current directory, and if so, print out its contents like the first part.  I fear the File f = new File(args[0]) made be wrong also.  Thanks for all your help.

```
public class DirSort {



// START MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // if no command line arguments, list directory
    if (args.length==0){
    File f = new File(".");
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

        // for each File in array, print out
        for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%8d %s %s%n", files[i].length(), df.format(files[i].lastModified()), files[i].getName());
            System.exit(0);
        }

    //NOT WORKING
    if(args.length==1){
        if (!args[0].isDirectory)
        System.exit(1);

    File f = new File(args[0]);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

        // for each File in array, print out
        for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%8d %s %s%n", files[i].length(), df.format(files[i].lastModified()), files[i].getName());
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should **read** the error message from the compiler. It tells you what and where the errors are. `args[0]` is a String. Strings don't have a field named `isDirectory`.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  How do I go about checking to see if args[0] is a directory? And if it is, create a new File object to list its contents like I do with the current directory.

Comment: An object of type File allows checking if the file is a directory. You can create an object of type File from a String. In addition to error messages, you should also read the javadoc of the classes you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `isDirectory` in the `String` class. You need to create a `File` object and then check if it is a directory or not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// if no command line arguments, list directory
if (args.length==0){
File f = new File(".");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

    // for each File in array, print out
    for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("%8d %s %s%n", files[i].length(), df.format(files[i].lastModified()), files[i].getName());
        System.exit(0);
    }

//NOT WORKING
if(args.length==1){


File f = new File(args[0]);
if (!f.isDirectory())
    System.exit(1);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

    // for each File in array, print out
    for (int i =0; i<files.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("%8d %s %s%n", files[i].length(), df.format(files[i].lastModified()), files[i].getName());
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: this isn't working... it compiles but not listing contents of directory specified in args[0] in the command line parameter.

Comment: oh nevermind i found the bug.  Had to take out the System.exit(0) from the second for loop.  Thanks for your help!